# How to make a function in jQuery last longer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

When I click on one of the buttons with "arrow" class the whole nav is disappearing. (other than that, the jquery code is working well). But why it is happening? I want the whole nav to disappear when I click on the ".btn" again and not when I click on the button.arrow...

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("click");
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
nav.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

nav.sidebar.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="btn">
  <span class="fas fa-cog"></span>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `.arrow` elements are nested within the `.btn` element, so a click on an arrow is also a click on the button.

To avoid this, you could stop the event that is triggered by arrows from propagating to the button.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("click");
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
});

$('.arrow').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do other work that should happen
  // because an arrow got clicked
  console.log("You clicked on  an arrow element.");
});
```

```css
nav.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

nav.sidebar.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="btn">
  <span class="fas fa-cog"></span>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.btn` to toggle ONLY if the click event occured directly on the cog icon...

```js
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
  if($(event.target).is(".fa-cog")){
    $(this).toggleClass("click");
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
nav.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

nav.sidebar.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="btn">
  <span class="fas fa-cog"></span>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
  </nav>
</main>
```

I could also be as simple as this:

```js
$('.fa-cog').click(function() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
nav.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

nav.sidebar.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="btn">
  <span class="fas fa-cog"></span>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">X <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
    <button class="arrow">Y <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
  </nav>
</main>
```